# getting specific parent nodes depending on child nodes XML in c# LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have a long `XML` which has parent node as `sdnEntry` and every parent has its child `sdnType` which define the type of entry. **I am trying to get only nodes which has `sdnType` to `Individual`.**

short sample of my xml is here;

```
<sdnEntry>
    <uid>6905</uid>
    <lastName>abc</lastName>
    <sdnType>Entity</sdnType> // type is entity

    <akaList>
    <aka>
        <uid>4741</uid>
        <type>a.k.a.</type>
        <category>strong</category>
        <lastName>ABC</lastName>
        <firstName>ABCCCC</firstName>
    </aka>
    <aka>
        <uid>4742</uid>
        <type>a.k.a.</type>
        <category>weak</category>
        <lastName>ADCS</lastName>
    </aka>
    </akaList>

    <nationalityList>
        <nationality>
        <uid>5416</uid>
        <country>XYZ</country>
        <mainEntry>true</mainEntry>
        </nationality>
    </nationalityList>
</sdnEntry>

<sdnEntry>
    <uid>6905</uid>
    <lastName>abc</lastName>
    <sdnType>Individual</sdnType> // type is individual

    <akaList>
    <aka>
        <uid>4741</uid>
        <type>a.k.a.</type>
        <category>strong</category>
        <lastName>ABC</lastName>
        <firstName>ABCCCC</firstName>
    </aka>
    <aka>
        <uid>4742</uid>
        <type>a.k.a.</type>
        <category>weak</category>
        <lastName>ADCS</lastName>
    </aka>
    </akaList>

    <nationalityList>
        <nationality>
        <uid>5416</uid>
        <country>XYZ</country>
        <mainEntry>true</mainEntry>
        </nationality>
    </nationalityList>
</sdnEntry>

<sdnEntry>
    <uid>6905</uid>
    <lastName>abc</lastName>
    <sdnType>Individual</sdnType>

    <akaList>
    <aka>
        <uid>4741</uid>
        <type>a.k.a.</type>
        <category>strong</category>
        <lastName>ABC</lastName>
        <firstName>ABCCCC</firstName>
    </aka>
    <aka>
        <uid>4742</uid>
        <type>a.k.a.</type>
        <category>weak</category>
        <lastName>ADCS</lastName>
    </aka>
    </akaList>

    <nationalityList>
        <nationality>
        <uid>5416</uid>
        <country>XYZ</country>
        <mainEntry>true</mainEntry>
        </nationality>
    </nationalityList>
</sdnEntry>

<sdnEntry>
    <uid>6905</uid>
    <lastName>abc</lastName>
    <sdnType>Entity</sdnType>

    <akaList>
    <aka>
        <uid>4741</uid>
        <type>a.k.a.</type>
        <category>strong</category>
        <lastName>ABC</lastName>
        <firstName>ABCCCC</firstName>
    </aka>
    <aka>
        <uid>4742</uid>
        <type>a.k.a.</type>
        <category>weak</category>
        <lastName>ADCS</lastName>
    </aka>
    </akaList>

    <nationalityList>
        <nationality>
        <uid>5416</uid>
        <country>XYZ</country>
        <mainEntry>true</mainEntry>
        </nationality>
    </nationalityList>
</sdnEntry>
```

my code is like this but I am getting error;

```
 var lXelements = XElement.Parse(xml);
 var lParentNode = "sdnEntry";
  if (lParentNode == "sdnEntry")
            {
 //lXelements = (XElement)lXelements.Descendants("sdnType").Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Individual");
                lXelements = (XElement)lXelements.Descendants("sdnType").Where(x => (string)x.Value == "Individual");
            }
```

I am getting casting error currently, I don't my this code will give me result as I want or not.

**error:**

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]' to type
>   'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'.

Comment: You do not need both (string) and Value.  It is redundant.  Use just (string).  You are using lXelements  for both the document and the output of the query.  Use a second variable.

Comment: Can you provide a **complete, well-formed** sample of the XML you are trying to parse?  When I upload your XML to https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ I get an error on line 31, *The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.*  If I try to parse the XML in .Net, `XElement.Parse()` throws an exception, see: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pg2jzK.  The reason the solutions here are not working for you may be because the root element and other elements containing your `<sdnEntry>` elements are missing, and when we try to fix this our guess how to do it does not match your file.

Comment: In fact a [mcve] would be ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to reassign the Linq `Where` result  to an `XElement`.

That aside, you basically want to get all `<sdnEntry>` nodes that have a child `<sdnType>Individual</sdnType>`

```
XElement elements = XElement.Parse(xml);
var parentNode = "sdnEntry";
var childNode = "sdnType";
var childNodeValue = "Individual";
List<XElement> entries = elements
    .Descendants(parentNode)
    .Where(parent => parent.Descendants(childNode)
        .Any(child => child.Value == childNodeValue)
    ).ToList();
```

`entries` should contain only the desired parent elements that match the provided child element filter.

The approach above searched for child nodes based on the parent node.

The following approach finds the child nodes first and then looks up the tree for the parent node

```
List<XElement> entries = elements
    .Descendants(childNode)
    .Where(child => child.Value == childNodeValue)
    .SelectMany(child => child.Ancestors(parentNode))
    .ToList();
```

Both approaches produced the same 2 matching elements result based on the following XML

```
var xml = @"
<sdnList>
    <sdnEntry>
        <uid>6905</uid>
        <lastName>abc</lastName>
        <sdnType>Entity</sdnType>

        <akaList>
        <aka>
            <uid>4741</uid>
            <type>a.k.a.</type>
            <category>strong</category>
            <lastName>ABC</lastName>
            <firstName>ABCCCC</firstName>
        </aka>
        <aka>
            <uid>4742</uid>
            <type>a.k.a.</type>
            <category>weak</category>
            <lastName>ADCS</lastName>
        </aka>
        </akaList>

        <nationalityList>
            <nationality>
            <uid>5416</uid>
            <country>XYZ</country>
            <mainEntry>true</mainEntry>
            </nationality>
        </nationalityList>
    </sdnEntry>

    <sdnEntry>
        <uid>6905</uid>
        <lastName>abc</lastName>
        <sdnType>Individual</sdnType> 

        <akaList>
        <aka>
            <uid>4741</uid>
            <type>a.k.a.</type>
            <category>strong</category>
            <lastName>ABC</lastName>
            <firstName>ABCCCC</firstName>
        </aka>
        <aka>
            <uid>4742</uid>
            <type>a.k.a.</type>
            <category>weak</category>
            <lastName>ADCS</lastName>
        </aka>
        </akaList>

        <nationalityList>
            <nationality>
            <uid>5416</uid>
            <country>XYZ</country>
            <mainEntry>true</mainEntry>
            </nationality>
        </nationalityList>
    </sdnEntry>

    <sdnEntry>
        <uid>6905</uid>
        <lastName>abc</lastName>
        <sdnType>Individual</sdnType>

        <akaList>
        <aka>
            <uid>4741</uid>
            <type>a.k.a.</type>
            <category>strong</category>
            <lastName>ABC</lastName>
            <firstName>ABCCCC</firstName>
        </aka>
        <aka>
            <uid>4742</uid>
            <type>a.k.a.</type>
            <category>weak</category>
            <lastName>ADCS</lastName>
        </aka>
        </akaList>

        <nationalityList>
            <nationality>
            <uid>5416</uid>
            <country>XYZ</country>
            <mainEntry>true</mainEntry>
            </nationality>
        </nationalityList>
    </sdnEntry>

    <sdnEntry>
        <uid>6905</uid>
        <lastName>abc</lastName>
        <sdnType>Entity</sdnType>

        <akaList>
        <aka>
            <uid>4741</uid>
            <type>a.k.a.</type>
            <category>strong</category>
            <lastName>ABC</lastName>
            <firstName>ABCCCC</firstName>
        </aka>
        <aka>
            <uid>4742</uid>
            <type>a.k.a.</type>
            <category>weak</category>
            <lastName>ADCS</lastName>
        </aka>
        </akaList>

        <nationalityList>
            <nationality>
            <uid>5416</uid>
            <country>XYZ</country>
            <mainEntry>true</mainEntry>
            </nationality>
        </nationalityList>
    </sdnEntry>
</sdnList>
";
```

Comment: it has returned 0 entries

Comment: @trighati I tested the code here https://dotnetfiddle.net/YNbLj7 using your sample xml and got 2 entries .

Comment: @trighati is the XML you provided accurate? I ask because there is no Root element. The answer is based on the provided XML

Comment: it has <sdnList> root node.

Comment: @trighati I have tested the XML using multiple approaches and get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following and see if it will help you: this does not use lambda expressions but does the same as Nkosi code above

```
 XElement xe = XElement.Parse(xml);
        IEnumerable<XElement> newlist = (from x in xe.Elements("sdnEntry")
                                         where x.Element("sdnType").Value == "Individual"
                                         select x);
       ///Then at this point newlist contains all xelement where the sdnType=Individual
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast `IEnumerable<XElement>` to `XElement`. Take away the cast  and it should work:

```
lXelements = lXelements.Descendants("sdnType")
          .Where(x => (string)x.Value == "Individual");

...

foreach(var element in lXelements)
{
   DoSomething(element);
}
```